# Creating and looping through array of bools

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, boolean

I'm creating a jigsaw application. When each piece is touched, the idea is that a bool (`droppedInPlace`) is assigned `YES` if it is put in its correct place, and `NO` if it is dropped in the wrong place. I then think I need to create an array of 40 bools (the number of jigsaw pieces), each of these entries will be initially set to NO.

This bool (`droppedInPlace`) is then inserted into an array using `replaceObjectAtIndex`. I then want to loop through this array. If all entries are true/yes/1, then the jigsaw is completed and i'll run some code.

I'm having some trouble doing this. I can't figure out how to code my idea above. Below is my code:

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
UIView *touchedView = [touch view];
// filename to be read from
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      pathForResource: 
                      @"jigsawHomeCenterPoints" 
                      ofType:@"plist"];
// array of cgpoints in string format
NSArray *jigsawHomeCentersArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
// the tag number of the selected image
int tag = touchedView.tag;
NSLog(@"tag: %i", tag);
// says that the piece has not been dropped in it's holder
bool droppedInPlace = NO;
// if what has been touched is part of the array of images
if ([imagesJigsawPieces indexOfObject:touchedView] != NSNotFound) {
    // preparing new snap-to-center position
    // using (tag-1) as an index in the HomeCentersArray corresponds to where the image should be placed
    // this was a conscious decision to make the process easier
    CGPoint newcenter = CGPointFromString([jigsawHomeCentersArray objectAtIndex:tag-1]);
    // the location of the current touch
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    // call the animate method upon release
    [self animateReleaseTouch:touchedView withLocation:location];
    // setting a proximity range - if it is within this 80x80 area the image will snap to it's corresponding holder (HomeCenter)
    if (location.x > newcenter.x-40 && location.x < newcenter.x+40 
        && location.y > newcenter.y-40 && location.y < newcenter.y+40) {
        touchedView.center = newcenter;
        touchedView.alpha = 1.0;
        droppedInPlace = YES;
    } else {
        touchedView.alpha = 0.5;
        droppedInPlace = NO;
    }
    NSLog(@"True or false: %i", droppedInPlace);
[self checkJigsawCompleted:droppedInPlace withTag:tag];
}
}
```

And the check function:

```
-(void) checkJigsawCompleted:(BOOL)inPlace withTag:(NSInteger)tag {
NSMutableArray *piecesInPlace;
[piecesInPlace replaceObjectAtIndex:tag-1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:inPlace]];
//code to loop through array - check if all entries are true/yes/1
//if so, jigsaw is completed - run some other code
//else, do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know how to loop through an array?  You can use a `for(;;)` loop or a `for(.. in ..)` loop or, my favourite for this sort of thing:  [-enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW19)

```
__block jigsawIsComplete = true;
[piecesInPlace enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id obj, NSUInteger i, BOOL* stop)
    {
        jigsawIsComplete = jigSawIsComplete && [obj boolValue];
        *stop = !jigsawIsComplete;
    }];
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that your `piecesInPlace` array is not initialized in method `checkJigsawCompleted` and will crash on the next line.

Suppose it IS initialized with the correct values, the way to check if all values are true is simple :

```
for (NSNumber *boolNumber in piecesInPlace) {
    if (![boolNumber boolValue])
       return false;
}

return true;
```

**EDIT :** or better yet :

```
return ![piecesInPlace containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
```

Answer (score 1):

So, a few things. First of all, you're replacing objects in this piecesInPlace mutable array based on the tag of the puzzle piece, it looks like. You never set the tag of those views, though. So, this line:

```
int tag = touchedView.tag;
```

will always be 0. What's worse, your replaceObjectAtIndex:tag-1 bit will try to access the -1 index of the array which isn't (at this time, but will be once Apple makes some changes public) legal.

As far as just looping through the array and checking for a true value, I would suggest using the method

```
- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block
```

Using this, you can just set the stop pointer to YES once you find a NO value in your array and the enumeration will end. You only want to continue enumerating as long as stop is NO. If you make it through your array without stopping, all the values are YES.

Comment: I have actually given all the images tags, from 1-40 in my storyboard. Would it make sense to use `replaceObjectAtIndex:(tag-1)`? Will those brackets ensure that i won't try to access the -1 index?

Comment: Think about it. If the first tag is 0, how will parentheses prevent tag - 1 from being -1? Of course, if you're manually setting the tags in IB, just start the lowest tag at 1 and you'll be fine.

Comment: Sorry, i think we got our wires crossed there-i though you meant something else. My lowest tag is, indeed, 1.

Comment: No worries. But regardless, the answer to your question is enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: